# Removing duplicate rows by selecting only those with minimum length value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two string columns: `Name` and `Code`. `Code` is unique, but `Name` is not. Sample data:

```
Name      Code
--------  ----
Jacket    15
Jeans     003
Jeans     26
```

I want to select unique rows with the smallest `Code` value, but not in terms of numeric value; rather, the length of the string. Of course this does not work:

```
SELECT Name, Min(Code) as Code
FROM Clothes
GROUP BY Name, Code
```

The above code will return one row for Jeans like such:

```
Jeans | 003
```

That is correct, because as a number, `003` is less than `26`. But not in my application, which cares about the length of the value, not the actual value. A value with a length of three characters is greater than a value with two characters. I actually need it to return this:

```
Jeans | 26
```

Because the *length* of `26` is shorter than the *length* of `003`.

So how do I write SQL code that will select row that has the code with the minimum length, not the actual minimum value? I tried doing this:

```
SELECT Name, Min(Len(Code)) as Code
FROM Clothes
GROUP BY Name, Code
```

The above returns me only a single character so I end up with this:

```
Jeans | 2
```

Comment: @Malachi, that is a terrible edit. He's saying he wants the one with the minimum length, and used an *example* of 3 digits. If he had another type of clothes where there were codes `'00005'` and `'5555'`, he'd want the one with 4 digits. Please don't try and think for the OP - your edit should have been rejected but apparently three approvers weren't paying attention. Also why not removing the first paragraph???

Comment: I agree. i apologize. the main thing was that it wasn't clear enough to people that the OP was trying to find the codes where the Length of the Code was less than the norm for the data. I read between the lines and thought I made that apparent based on the information given. the edit given accurately shows this now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT Name, Code, rn = ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY LEN(Code))
    FROM dbo.Clothes
)
SELECT Name, Code
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6b45/1)

If you have multiple values of code that share the same length, the choice will be arbitrary, so you can break the tie by adding an additional order by clause, e.g.

```
OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY LEN(Code), CONVERT(INT, Code) DESC)
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/038c0/1)

Comment: Nicely done - thank you! I've never come across the ";WITH cte AS" syntax before. I have plenty of SQL books, but I simply didn't know what chapter to look at because I don't know what I should be looking for in the first place. Voted as answer.

Comment: @volumeone that is a common table expression. It's not essential in this case but I find it's easier to follow than a derived table. "Here is the set of things I'm identifying; now here is what I'm going to do with that set."

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select clothes.name, MIN(code)
from clothes
    inner join
    (
        SELECT 
            Name, Min(Len(Code)) as CodeLen
        FROM
            clothes 
        GROUP BY
        Name
    ) results
on clothes.name = results.name
and LEN(clothes.code) = results.CodeLen
group by clothes.name
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to sort on the numeric value of the Code field. If so, the correct approach would be to cast it to INT first, and use that for sorting/min functions (in a subquery), then select the original code in your main query clause.

Comment: No, they are trying to sort by the *length* of the numeric value.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I read "I want to select unique rows with the minimum "Code" value." as the actual requirement, in spite of the phrasing of the question, which, as the OP admitted, is confusing.

Comment: I'll quote: `that will select the minimum length, not the actual minimum value` and the attempt to use `Name, Min(Len(Code))`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'm just saying the question is confusing, and quoted part of it myself that *seemed* to be the "real" question, in case that's what he's looking for. Not arguing that you're wrong, just that I can't tell from the phrasing of the question.

Comment: I think the first instance of "minimum value" was just stating that min() is the logical operation he wants, but he is treating "value" a different way. I've updated the question to hopefully make that more clear.